# Remove all string before nth occurrence of a character in a column

Tags: python, string

I have a data frame column and I would like to remove all strings before the 4th space.

I have tried something like this but it didn't work:

```py
df = df[df['Missing'].split(" ")[4]
```

Can anyone please help me out with this? Much appreciated!

```
Missing
Row 2: unknown name: Petiq
Row 3: unknown company: Hyundai Heavy Industries
Row 31: unknown name: Ronald Ibérica
Row 42: unknown company: Chick-Fil-A
Row 48: unknown brand: Renault
```

Desired output:

```
Missing
Petiq
Hyundai Heavy Industries
Ronald Ibérica
Chick-Fil-A
Renault
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df.Missing = df.Missing.str.split(" ", n=4).str[-1]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                    Missing
0                     Petiq
1  Hyundai Heavy Industries
2            Ronald Ibérica
3               Chick-Fil-A
4                   Renault
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can just split on `:`  and take the last substring from the list.

```py
df['Missing'].str.split(': ').str[-1]

0                       Petiq
1    Hyundai Heavy Industries
2              Ronald Ibérica
3                 Chick-Fil-A
4                     Renault
Name: Missing, dtype: object
```